# What if the Pearls/Beads are not in a String or Rope?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, nouns

The collective noun for Pearls or Beads is Rope or String. But what if that's not the case?

Are pearls always seen in strings? No. What if they are collectively in something (like a bowl) freely without any rope or string?

Answer (score 1):

Since I like those colorful tiny objects, I would like to leave an answer here.

It's true that the plural of [bead](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bead) means a rosary or something similar.

However, the bead itself is a countable noun.

> "What if they are collectively in something (like a bowl) freely without any rope or string?"

I guess you are talking about something like this photo:

[image]

So, beads and pearls can also be used to describe a bunch of those objects.

Comment: Is there any proof on the internet that "Bunch" is the right answer?